# Probability distributions for Directed Cyclic Graphs

Tags: graphs, bayesian, bayesian-networks

Given a directed cyclic graph where vertex A is 'infected', and there are different infection probabilities between each node, what is the best approach towards computing the conditional probability $p(F|A)$?

[image: Directed Cyclic Graph]

Do I have to transform it into asyclic graph and use bayesian net-methods?

How would I proceed in order to design an algorithm for computing probabilities like this one, and are there approaches to this that are computationally feasible for very large networks?